# Menu not saving in dashboard

Tags: menus

I've created menus in wordpress dashboard countless times and never had a problem saving them until today. Getting this error:

"The menu name Main Menu conflicts with another menu name. Please try another."

Is this a permissions error or something else? I don't have another menu created. Hoping someone might have come across this and have some ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any other plugin or theme creating menus on your system?

Comment: WP usually gives good error messages so I would take it at face value.  Namely, there is already another menu with the name you have chosen.